Build softhsm2 and link library to own application using cmake
Anyone knows how to link a PKCS#11 interface specific SoftHSM - https://github.com/Zeno-sole/softhsm2/blob/master/README.md in CMakeList.txt. Basically, I want to build my application (which needs PKCS#11 interface) with SoftHSM library.
I am not able to link it, want to know how to build and link it.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read How do I ask a good question? - Especially the part on "Search, and research..."  You say, "I am not able to link it", but we need to know what you've tried (even if it's failed) so that other users don't waste your time (and theirs) suggesting things you've already done.  What have you researched? What have you tried? What were the results? Please Edit your question to provide additional details. Thanks!

Consider including a Minimal Reproducible Example that demonstrates your progress so far. Thanks!
